# Fast way to edit ftp files with command line on mac

Tags: wordpress, macos, command-line, ftp

I am fairly new to touching js for wordpress and I am tired of editing my js files within a program like filezilla and wonder, if there is a faster way to access and edit ftp files via mac command-line?

I am aware that there are no commands for opening and editing the files directly in ftp environment on mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first connect the SFTP via command line.

```
ssh username@hostname
```

Then enter the password and connect to server.

After that go to the path and type the following command to edit the file

```
sudo nano filename.php
```

You can do this with other extensions as well to edit the file via editor.For that you need to configure the editor with command line tools.